# BASH remove leading and trailing spaces in array

Tags: arrays, bash, whitespace

I've got data coming from mysql and some values have leading or trailing spaces.

This is the code I have:

```
IFS=$':' res=(${vals//$'\t'/:}) 

for (( i=0 ; i<${#res[@]} ; i++ )); do
    echo "$i: ${res[i]}*"
done
```

is there a simple effective way to ensure there are no leading or trailing space in `res[i]` ?

Thanks

**EDIT**
This is the result of my MYSQL query before it goes through IFS.

```
ZnbMF0 9RrO7 1 SiteA password password 12 1234 1234 456 456 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 test@domain.com test user 5 2222 0 0 0 0 server address 0 0 test@domain.com 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 NULL
```

In MySQL the email addresses have leading and trailing spaces.
Processing through IFS and then Looping though it as :

```
for (( i=0 ; i<${#res[@]} ; i++ )); do
    echo "$i: ${res[i]}*"
done
```

Results in:

```
0: ZnbMFO*
1: 9RrO7*
2: 1*
3: SiteA*
4: password*
5: password*
6: 12*
7: 1234*
8: 1234*
9: 456*
10: 456*
11: 0*
12: 0*
13: 0*
14: 0*
15: 0 *
16: 0*
17: 0*
18: 0*
19: test@domain.com *
20: test*
21: user*
22:  5*
23:  2222 *
24: 0*
25: 0 *
26: 0*
27: 0*
28: server*
29: address*
30: 0*
31: 0*
32:  test@domain.com *
33: 0*
34: 0*
35: 0*
36: 0*
37: 0*
38: 0*
39: 0 *
40: 0*
41:  0*
42: 0*
43: 0 *
44: 0*
45: 0*
46: NULL*
```

The `*` is there just to highlight the trailing space.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to remove the spaces in your array or just leave them out in the output?

Comment: What does the input look like? You're replacing tabs with colons and then split the string on colons, any reason you don't split on tabs directly? What does the desired output look like?

Comment: Please, if you want us to help you, post an example of the input you have (produced by mysql) and the corresponding output you want to get.

Comment: @Cyrus ideally I'd like to remove then from the array. Thanks  I'll try to get some sample data to show what happens.

Comment: I've edited the original post with data sample.

Comment: Do you want to remove only one space at the beginning and end or several consecutive spaces?

Comment: Anything at the beginning or end. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you have an array as this one:

```
arr=('foo bar' 'test@domain.com ' \
' test@domain.com ' '    test@domain.com         ')
```

To check array content using `printf`:

```
printf '[%s]\n' "${arr[@]}"
```

This will show:

```
[foo bar]
[test@domain.com ]
[ test@domain.com ]
[    test@domain.com         ]
```

Now for leading and trailing space removal:

```
shopt -s extglob                     # turn on extended glob
arr=( "${arr[@]/#+([[:blank:]])/}" ) # remove leading space/tab from each element
arr=( "${arr[@]/%+([[:blank:]])/}" ) # remove trailing space/tab from each element
```

Now if you print array again:

```
printf '[%s]\n' "${arr[@]}"
```

It will show:

```
[foo bar]
[test@domain.com]
[test@domain.com]
[test@domain.com]
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to do exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: This solution removes only one whitespace from the beginning and the end. It doesn't remove all leading and trailing whitespaces. Check with input=  arr=('   foo  bar   ')

Comment: Good point @akshay. I have edited answer to take care of multiple leading and trailing whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you would call it simple, but you can use sed:

```
echo "${res[i]}" | sed 's/^ *\| *$//g'
```

---

```
vals=$' a \t c d'
IFS=$':' res=(${vals//$'\t'/:})

for (( i=0 ; i<${#res[@]} ; i++ )); do
    echo X${res[i]}X
    res[$i]=$(echo "${res[i]}" | sed 's/^ *\| *$//g')
    echo X${res[i]}X
done
```

Output:

```
X a X
XaX
X c dX
Xc dX
```